# How to query the sql executed a month ago in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to query the SQL executed a month ago. Now, I have SQL_ID witch I collection a month ago, but I do not collection sql_text.

Answer (score 0):

All the info about previously executed queries can be found on the AWR views based on the sql_id:

- **DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT** for the text of your query;
- **DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT** for the query statistics like cpu_time, elapsed_time, number of executions and etc;
- **DBA_HIST_SQL_PLAN** for the execution plan;

To specify the timeframe do a join with the **SNAP_ID** column of the **DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT** view, filtering by the **BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME** column.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I only have AWR for 8 days. So I can't find SQL via AWR. I will change the AWR save policy and save AWR for a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can query by using

```
select sql_text, sql_fulltext 
  from gv$sql
 where sql_id = &i_sql_id
```

but it's not guaranteed that sql is still in the library cache.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I try to find sql_text with sql_id in v$sqlarea. But I can't find it. Maybe the time is too long, the library cache cannot hold it for a long time.